# How to create a cross-platform string definitions file for C# and Objective-C?

Tags: c#, objective-c, windows, macos, cross-platform

My app has a PC version written in C# and a Mac version written in Objective-C. I'd like to create a common strings file so my messaging to the user is consistent between apps. What's a good way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) they have libraries for [Objective-C](http://code.google.com/p/metasyntactic/wiki/ProtocolBuffers) and for [.NET](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) and its much lighter than XML and faster parsing as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use and XML file and store the resources there.